# How to play a .sdp file on VKPlayer in iOS?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, video-processing, serversocket

I have a **.sdp** file in my Xcode proj. And I am implementing **VideoKit** in my app. I have to call the **rtp** file and create a Client **Udp** Socket. And have to play the **.sdp** file on my *VKPlayer* (videokit).

I added `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` class and import also.

In my VC I implemented below code :

```
#import "PGDummyP2PViewController.h"
#import "GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h"
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

NSBundle *mainBundle;
NSString *filepath;
NSData *fileData;
NSUInteger length;
NSUInteger packetSize;
unsigned char mybytes[2];
GCDAsyncUdpSocket * sendUdpSocket;

@interface PGDummyP2PViewController ()

@end

@implementation PGDummyP2PViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"P2P";

    [self createClientUdpSocket];

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Add code here to do background processing
        [self rtpReader];

        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Add code here to update the UI/send notifications based on the
            // results of the background processing
        });
    });
     [self configureVideoPlayerView];

     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)configureVideoPlayerView {
    self.videoPlayer = [[VKPlayerController alloc] init];
    self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = kVKPlayerControlStyleNone;
    self.videoPlayer.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.videoPlayer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
    [self.videoPlayer.view autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.videoPlayer.view];
    self.videoPlayer.contentURLString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"sdp"];
    [self.videoPlayer play];

 }

 -(void) rtpReader
 {
     mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
     filepath = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"VideoPackets" ofType: @"rtp"];
     NSFileHandle * fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filepath];

     fileData = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:2];
     length = (int) fileData.length;

     // NSUInteger size = [fileData length] / sizeof(unsigned char);
     const char* fileBytes = (const char*)[fileData bytes];
     NSUInteger index;

     for (index = 0; index<length; index++)
     {
        char aByte = fileBytes[index];
        mybytes[index]=aByte;
     }

     while ((length!=0)) {

        packetSize = [self convertByteArrayToDecimal:mybytes];
        fileData = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:packetSize];
        NSLog(@"The file data size is :%lu",(unsigned long)fileData.length);
        [self sendmyData:fileData];


       if(length !=0)
       {
           fileData = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:2];
           length = (int) fileData.length;

           //NSUInteger size = [fileData length] / sizeof(unsigned char);
           const char* fileBytes = (const char*)[fileData bytes];
           NSUInteger index;

           for (index = 0; index<length; index++)
           {
               char aByte = fileBytes[index];
               mybytes[index]=aByte;
           }
       }
    }
    [fileHandle closeFile];
}

 -(unsigned long) convertByteArrayToDecimal:(unsigned char[])myByteArray
 {
     unsigned long decimal;
     decimal = ((myByteArray[0] & 0xff) <<8 | (myByteArray[1] & 0xff));
     //    NSLog(@" The data size is :%lu",decimal);
     return decimal;
 }

 -(void)createClientUdpSocket
 {
     dispatch_queue_t dQueue = dispatch_queue_create("client udp socket", NULL);

     sendUdpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue: dQueue socketQueue: nil];

     /*if(![sendUdpSocket bindToPort:5006 error:nil]){
      NSLog(@"bindToPort Failed");
     }*/

     [sendUdpSocket receiveOnce:nil];
     [sendUdpSocket joinMulticastGroup:[self getIPAddress] error:nil];
     NSLog(@"Ready");

 }

  // Public interface for sending data.
   -(void)sendmyData:(NSData *)data
   {
         [sendUdpSocket sendData:data toHost:[self getIPAddress]port:5006 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
   //    NSLog(@"sent message to server");
   }
 - (NSString *)getIPAddress {

    NSString *address = @"error";
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;
    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0) {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL) {
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                    // Get NSString from C String
                    address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];

                 }

             }

            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
         }
     }
     // Free memory
     freeifaddrs(interfaces);
     return address;
 }
 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
      [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
 @end
```

But my issue is my video player is always blank screen. If I am playing any .mp4 file then its playing fine. but its decoding the .sdp file and not playing.

Please anyone guide me.